# Mutations not registering using computed properties in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I have a system that uses a lot of form components to live update a view based on the inputted information. When I first built the app I was mostly using v-model, the local component data, and vue save state to keep the data in local storage so it persisted when they reloaded the page.

However when I moved over to vuex as the program expanded, this was not so straightforward so I decided to use v-model with computed properties using getters and setters so I wouldn't have to write on change functions for over 50 different inputs. I also realized that you can create one computed variable for an object and still use v-model to access and update properties of that object, like so:

```
  <div v-for="prof in info.profs">
  <textarea v-model="prof.name" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
  <textarea v-model="prof.email" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea>
  <textarea v-model="prof.office" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea> <br>
  </div>

info: {
  get () {
    return this.$store.getters.getInfo
  },
  set (payload) {
    this.$store.commit('updateInfo', payload)
  }
},
```

This works perfectly, with the store updating the data for each property without having to create their own separate computed variables, but for some reason it doesn't show up as a committed mutation "updateInfo" on the vue chrome dev tools and when I use a local storage plugin for vuex like vuex-persistedstate or vuex-persist it doesnt change the localstorage data until I commit another mutation that is structured normally. Right now my workaround is to create a local copy of the property in the component and then watch that property for changes and commit to the store, which lets me use the component level localstorage mixin again, but I feel like there has to be a better way to do this that does not involve writing a change function or a computed variable for each property in info as that would be quite verbose in this application.

```
data () {
return {
  info: this.$store.getters.getInfo
 }
},
watch: {
info: function(payload){
  this.$store.commit('updateInfo', payload)
 }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both ways are wrong. Add `strict: true` to your store and you'll see errors being thrown in both cases.

In both alternatives the `prof`'s `name`, `email` and `office` properties are being modified directly (which is against the Vuex principles that dictates every change should happen through mutations).

Similarly, not that computed setter (first case), nor that watcher (second case) are being triggered because you aren't modifying `item`, but deeply nested properties of it (e.g. `name`).

---

The simplest solution, which would allow you to still **use a mixin**, is to ditch `v-model` and use the `:value` and `@input` bindings. Example:

```
<textarea :value="prof.name" @input="updateProf(prof, 'name', $event)" >
```

Notice that it uses a `updateProf` method, which commits the mutation (see below) and goes in the mixin.

This way all modification are done within mutations. One final note, if you vind the use of  `:value` and `@input` verbose, you can create a [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) to handle it.

[**JSFiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ch6jqj00/) or demo (same code) below.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    info: {
        profs: [
        {name: "Alice", email: "alice@example.com", office: "NY"},
        {name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com", office: "CA"}
      ]
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateProf(state, {prof, prop, value}) {
        prof[prop] = value;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getInfo: state => {
      return state.info
    }
  }
});
const mixin = {
  computed: {
    info() {
      return this.$store.getters.getInfo
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateProf(prof, prop, e) {
        this.$store.commit('updateProf', {prof, prop, value: e.target.value})
    }
    }
}
new Vue({
  store,
  mixins: [mixin],
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
  <div v-for="prof in info.profs">
    <hr>
    name: <textarea :value="prof.name" @input="updateProf(prof, 'name', $event)" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea> <br>
    email: <textarea :value="prof.email" @input="updateProf(prof, 'email', $event)" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea> <br>
    office: <textarea :value="prof.office" @input="updateProf(prof, 'office', $event)" class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Keeping `v-model`**

Just so nobody tells I didn't say it was possible, here's one way you could do to keep using `v-model`. The key point in this alternative is the functions that do deep cloning and deep equals. I have provided two simple/naive implementations, YMMV:

[**JSFiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/bekqv4pm/1/). Demo (same code as fiddle) below:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    info: {
        profs: [
        {name: "Alice", email: "alice@example.com", office: "NY"},
        {name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com", office: "CA"}
      ]
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateInfo(state, data) {
        state.info = data
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getInfo: state => {
      return state.info
    }
  }
});

// these two functions are key here
// consider using other implementations if you have more complicated property types, like Dates
function deepClone(o) { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)); }
function deepEquals(o1, o2) { return JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2) }

const mixin = {
    data() {
    return {
      info: deepClone(this.$store.getters.getInfo),
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getInfo() {
      return this.$store.getters.getInfo;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    getInfo: {
        deep: true,
        handler(newInfo) {
        if (!deepEquals(newInfo, this.info)) { // condition to prevent infinite loops
                this.info = deepClone(newInfo);
        }
        }
    },
    info: {
        deep: true,
        handler(newInfo) {
            this.$store.commit('updateInfo', deepClone(newInfo))
        }
    }
    }
}
new Vue({
  store,
  mixins: [mixin],
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
  <div v-for="prof in info.profs">
    <hr>
    name: <textarea v-model="prof.name"  class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea> <br>
    email: <textarea v-model="prof.email"  class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea> <br>
    office: <textarea v-model="prof.office"  class="code-input uk-input" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew both ways were not standard practice and that I should use value and input bindings, but was trying to avoid it being too verbose as there are many different data types in the store, including dates. I think the custom directive will definitely help so thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was originally thinking of doing something like the update Prof function you have here , where it passes the key as an argument, but there are many objects that are more than one level deep so it would have required many separate functions. That's flux though I guess. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep!! Let me know if anything comes up (you can always open a new question and ping me here, if you want)!

Comment: Ah, and about this one, I see you are new here, so, if you think the answer does de job, you can consider accepting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205

Comment: Ah[2], I see you just mention the first alternative. But do check the second as well. If you have plain data (so that that clone function works good enough) it might be the best/shorter solution overall!